# How to send int with IFormFileCollection in one POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to upload images (I'm using `IFormFileCollection`), but also need to get an additional data (simple int value) in same POST request.

my controller looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Guid>>> Create(IFormFileCollection uploads, int id) { }
```

my cshtml which I'm using to test it looks like this:

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="ProjectMedia" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploads" /><br>
    <input type="file" name="uploads" /><br>
    <input type="number" name="id" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I don't have any problem with receiving files to upload, but I don't get anything but them. id is always default 0.
I also tried to set in with `asp-route`, but got the same 0 at controller.
Is there any opportunities to send `IFormFileCollection` and int in one request? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: you should put route in your controller. public async Task<ActionResult<List<Guid>>> Create(IFormFileCollection uploads,[FromRoute] int id) { } then in your api call just put your integer value in route with slash example "/create/id"

Comment: or you can name your route on top of your controller method attribute [HttpPost], put [Route("create/{id:int}")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[FromForm]` attribute to explicitly tell the model binder where to get the data for the action

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Guid>>> Create([FromForm]IFormFileCollection uploads, [FromForm]int id) { 
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)